# Как вставить изображение (фигура сквирл + прозрачность) в другое изображение?

Tags: python-3.x, pillow

Использую библиотеку PIL (Pillow)
Мне нужно вставить фигуру, а именно сквирл (это квадрат с закруглёнными концами) в изображение (фон для него). При этом нужно настроить прозрачнось этой фигуры.
У меня получается просто вставить эту фигуру, но прозрачность настроить не могу. За маску я взял другое изображение этой же фигуры, но на чёрном фоне, а так же сделал фигуру поменьше чтобы при обрезке края были нормально обрезаны, а не с кусками чёрного фона в некоторых местах.
Вот мой код:

```
background = Image.open('Background-3k×4.5k.png')
figure = Image.open('Figure-2380×2.png')

mask = Image.open('Figure_Mask-2380×2.png').resize(figure.size).convert('L')
background.paste(figure, (310, 1785), mask)
background.save('Result.png')

background.close()
mask.close()
```

Больше одного изображения прикрепить нельзя, так что выберу только саму фигуру (она без фона).
И да - она белая)
[image: Фигура]

Comment: Всё, я уже сам решил эту проблему.

Comment: Значит так, я вставил фигуру в копию фона, потом аккуратно вырезал, чтобы получился квадрат. Следом я выбрал получившуюся картинку маской и обрезал её квадратом в полный её размер. И в поле fill можно теперь указывать значения от 0 до 255 - это как раз прозрачность.